# Complete and powerful serial terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, serial-port

After the switch to Ubuntu 19.10 the most important application I miss is a serial terminal.
Under Windows I used [RealTerm](https://realterm.sourceforge.io/) every day. I tried some of the Linux alternative (i.e. CuteCom, CoolTerm, etc...) none of them can compete against RealTerm.

Unfortunately I also have troubles to run it under Wine.

Is there any *good* serial terminal under Linux, even payware?
I need, at least:

- change format (raw, vt100, hex, hex+ascii, binary, nibble, 5/16/32/float, etc...) *on the fly*
- capture and send file options (overwrite/append/timestamp, char/line/file delay, repeat)
- sync options (leading/trailing char, ...)
- pin's state
- send as number/hex/ascii
- append cr/lf/crc